# $(p+(2-p^2)/r)^2 <2 \implies 2pr+2-p^2 < r^2$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I was told that I can get from the equation $(1)$ to equation $(2)$.
I tried playing with the numbers in everyway, but I couldn't think a way to get $(2)$ from $(1)$.

> $(1) (p+(2-p^2)/r)^2 <2$
>
> $(2) 2pr+2-p^2 < r^2$

I feel like I am missing something obvious but I can't figure it out so some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you might like to provide more context.

Comment: Might there be typo(s)? Multiplying (1) by $r^2$ yields $(pr+2-p^2)^2 < 2r^2$, which is somewhat close to (2).

Comment: The previous answer had the right idea. When $p=r=2$, (1) holds but not (2). In fact this implication fails for $|p|>\sqrt 2$ and $|r-p| < \sqrt 2$, according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28p%2B+%282-p%5E%282%29%29%2F%28r%29%29%5E2%3C2+and+2pr%2B2-p%5E2%3E%3Dr%5E2)